# Workaround for Sass variable interpolation in nested loop?

Tags: css, sass

I realize this is a big issue is Sass right now, and have looked at some of the solutions out there but I have a set of maps, and I am trying to create a loop as in:

```
    //Color chords
$chord1: (color1:orange,  color2: magenta, color3: gray, color4: yellow);
$chord2: (color1:magenta, color2: blue,    color3: gray, color4: orange);

%fillcolor {

}

@for $c from 1 through 8 {
    #chord#{$c} {
        @for $i from 1 through 4 {
            .color#{$i} {
                $c1: map-get($chord#{$c}, color#{$i});
                fill: $c1;
                color: $c1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sass (3.4.5), of course, is choking on `$chord#{$c}` ("cannot find variable $chord").

Is there a work-around in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use dynamic variable name in SCSS for now but you could use list as shown below.

```
//Color chords
$chord: (
  (color1:orange,  color2: magenta, color3: gray, color4: yellow)
  (color1:magenta, color2: blue,    color3: gray, color4: orange)
);

@for $c from 1 through length($chord) {
    $subList: nth($chord, $c);
    #chord#{$c} {
        @for $i from 1 through length( $subList ) {
            .color#{$i} {
                $c1: map-get( $subList, color#{$i});
                fill: $c1;
                color: $c1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you could also iterate on the $chord list, and avoid magic numbers...
See here a good article about list in SASS : http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/

Comment: That's a good solution.  Of course, it would be far easier to read to Sass would only allow interpolation in variable names.  Maybe someday.  Thanks, I'll use it.